# Not able to handle popups in selenium + IE9

Tags: selenium, popup, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to find the id of a popup window which opens when I click on a link using Selenium.

The code is

```
public String getWindowId() {
        String feedWinId = test.getEval("{var windowId; for(var x in                    selenium.browserbot.openedWindows ) {windowId=x;} }");
        return feedWinId;
        //return feedWinId.contains("chat");
    }
```

Now this is working for Firefox but it returns null on IE 9.Any idea why ? also is there a workaround for IE

P.S. My requirement is simply to check if a popup opened when the link was clicked.Once I get the WindowId, i use something like

```
test.waitForPopUp(getWindowId(), ResourceConstants.POPUP_TIMEOUT);
```

to check fo the popup

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `selenium.GetAllWindowIds();`?
Then switch to a window with `selenium.selectwindows(windowId);`and check if it is the popup you wish.

```
String[] ids = selenium.GetAllWindowIds();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
{
    selenium.WaitForPopUp(ids[i], "30000");
    selenium.selectwindow(pids[i]);
    //check if it is your popup
    //if yes then break;
}
```